# How to fill correctly the strokeDasharray

Tags: reactjs, svg, path

I'm trying to accomplish this... in this example  the green stroke is filled when the people selected (1), and the gray ones are the total of people (6)

[image: a]

other example is green stroke is filled (3) and total (6)

[image]

what I accomplished by now, it doesn't fill correctly,

[image]

```js
const [personQuantity, setPersonQuantity] = useState(2)
  const [payingFor, setPayingFor] = useState(1)


  useEffect(() => {
    let amountPerPerson = subtotal / personQuantity
    let perPerson = amountPerPerson * payingFor
    setPerPerson(perPerson)

    if (personQuantity >= payingFor && personQuantity > 2) {
      setActivate(true)
    } else {
      setActivate(false)
    }
  }, [personQuantity, payingFor])

  const fillPercentage = (payingFor / personQuantity) * 100

  return (
    <>
       
            <div className="h-20 w-20 ">
              <svg className="circular-chart " viewBox="0 0 36 36">
                <path
                  fill="none"
                  strokeWidth="4"
                  strokeDasharray={`${fillPercentage + 1},1`}
                  className="circle-bg bg-DARK_1 stroke-2 stroke-white"
                  d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
                />
                <path
                  strokeWidth="4"
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  fill="none"
                  className="circle stroke-LIGHT_GREEN_1  transition-opacity delay-150 ease-in-out"
                  strokeDasharray={`${fillPercentage}, 100`}
                  d="M18 2.0845
         a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
```

Comment: The total length of your path is 100. if you have 6 persons the length of the stroke for a person is 100/6, for 2 persons is 2*100/6. The stroke-dasharray takes a second value for the gap. If you have 1 person the gap is 100 - 100/6 or if you prepher 5*100/6. I would put 100/6 in a var

Comment: didnt work this.

Answer (score 0):

as stated by enxaneta, you use path of 100 percent, so you should make the math so that the white draws the person's number separated by a gap percent space and the green fills the number of slots including intermediate spaces.

So assuming subtotal is the total number of persons and payingFor is the number of persons that should be green, we have :

```
let pathSize = 100
let gapSize = 1
let percentForOne = (pathSize / subtotal)
let greenedPercent = (percentForOne * payingFor) - gapSize 
let notGreenedPercent = (percentForOne * (subtotal - payingFor)) + gapSize
```

so for white :

```
strokeDasharray={`${percentForOne} - ${gapSize},${gapSize}`}
```

then for green :

```
strokeDasharray={`${greenedPercent},${notGreenedPercent}`}
```

Please note that it will be incorrect with more than 100 persons because these would imply more than 100 gaps of 1 percent and negative space between them, so you should probably put the gapSize to 0 when subtotal is more than ~40 (esthetic value)

As a second note, while using a path to approximate a circle do work, I recommend using `<circle cx="18" cy="18" r="15.9155" pathlength=100>` and in both case you will need to rotate the figure by -90deg to achieve the vertical origin of the drawing `transform: rotate(-90deg)`

I did a demo on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Cajuteq/pen/LYJpzzJ) (with fixed values)

Comment: didndt work as spected, it doesnt make the divisions on the stroke

Comment: its between 2 variables, payingFor and personQuantity

Comment: the strokes are there and defined by gapSize, maybe 1 percent is not enough for you to see it on a small screen, did you tried opening the codepen ? or maybe you want green to also mark the strokes ?

Answer (score 0):

Authoring react in StackOverflow is painful so I wrote a response in pure HTML / CSS, but hopefully this can help you see how this would work.

Except for a bit of math, the initial issue is to be able to calculate the total length that you need to base your % calculations on. In this case I'm using a `<circle>` so it's trivial (2 * π * r), but if you absolutely need to use a `<path>` there is a native JS method `getTotalLength` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength) that can compute it for you.

```js
// in your case
const length = path.current.getTotalLength() // 100.0140609741211
```

```css
  /* in my case */
  --radius: 18;
  --length: calc(2 * 3.14 * var(--radius));
```

Then we use `stroke-dasharray` that has the syntax "length visible, length hidden".

For the segmented circle, the length hidden (`--gap`) is trivial and up to you. The length visible is simply `total / segments - gap`. For example, in  circle with 3 segments, there will also be 3 gaps, so no hidden trick here.

```css
--one: calc(var(--length) / var(--total));
stroke-dasharray: calc(var(--one) - var(--gap)), var(--gap)
```

For the progress circle, the visible length would be `total / segments * current` (and hidden length would be the rest). However we need to adjust for the gaps if you want it to stop at the same points that the segmented circle stops. Basically `-gap` for the visible length, and `+gap` for the hidden length.

```css
stroke-dasharray: calc(var(--one) * var(--current) - var(--gap)), calc((var(--total) - var(--current)) * var(--one) + var(--gap));
```

```css
#svg {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  --radius: 18;
  --length: calc(2 * 3.14 * var(--radius));
  --total: 6;
  --current: 2;
  --one: calc(var(--length) / var(--total));
  --gap: 1;
}

#segmented {
  stroke-dasharray: calc(var(--one) - var(--gap)), var(--gap);
}

#progress {
  stroke-dasharray: calc(var(--one) * var(--current) - var(--gap)), calc((var(--total) - var(--current)) * var(--one) + var(--gap));
}
```

```html
 <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
   <circle id="segmented" cx="18" cy="18" r="18" fill="none" strokeWidth="4" stroke="black" />
   <circle id="progress" cx="18" cy="18" r="18" fill="none" strokeWidth="4" stroke="green" />
</svg>
```

And just for fun, here's a full example with buttons so you can test the accuracy of this solution:

```js
let total = 6
let current = 2
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

function onChange() {
  svg.style.setProperty('--total', total)
  svg.style.setProperty('--current', current)
}

buttons.item(0).addEventListener('click', () => {
  total = Math.max(0, total-1)
  onChange()
})
buttons.item(1).addEventListener('click', () => {
  total += 1
  onChange()
})
buttons.item(2).addEventListener('click', () => {
  current = Math.max(0, current-1)
  onChange()
})
buttons.item(3).addEventListener('click', () => {
  current += 1
  onChange()
})
```

```css
#svg {
  overflow: visible;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  --radius: 18;
  --length: calc(2 * 3.14 * var(--radius));
  --total: 6;
  --current: 2;
  --one: calc(var(--length) / var(--total));
  --gap: 2;
}

#segmented {
  stroke-dasharray: calc(var(--one) - var(--gap)), var(--gap);
  transition: stroke-dasharray 300ms;
}

#progress {
  stroke-dasharray: calc(var(--one) * var(--current) - var(--gap)), calc((var(--total) - var(--current)) * var(--one) + var(--gap));
  transition: stroke-dasharray 300ms;
}
```

```html
 <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
   <circle id="segmented" cx="18" cy="18" r="18" fill="none" strokeWidth="4" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" />
   <circle id="progress" cx="18" cy="18" r="18" fill="none" strokeWidth="4" stroke="green" stroke-linecap="round" />
</svg>

<div>
  <button>-</button>
  total
  <button>+</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button>-</button>
  current
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```